# KDE is now gray! Fonts in konsole app are broken

Tags: kde, plasma, sddm

I just removed java 8 and after plasma restart fonts are broken, most of plasma apps changed white color to gray, taskbar is semi-transperent, context menu is gray.

https://puu.sh/xFBco/123e0d1f82.png

https://puu.sh/xFBcH/4a9bd1e6fe.png

Modal window with shutdown/logout buttons has unreadable fonts. Changing theme doesn't help, taskbar still transparent and gray. Disabling translucency effect doesn't help.

I tried to remove .kde and appletsrc.

Ubuntu 17.04, sddm. How to fix this?

Comment: Removing Java cannot result in that. What else did you do prior to noticing the problem?

Comment: I removed every package, that contains 'java' word, then restarted session.

Comment: Did you uninstalled by line-command? Look at `history` if something else was uninstalled with it.

Comment: *I removed every package, that contains 'java' word* Really? Well, that explains a lot. Unfortunately you may have to reinstall `kubuntu-desktop` if not Kubuntu itself. That's NOT how you uninstall software.

Comment: I have purged this packages:
openjdk-8-jre openjdk-9-jre java-common libapache-pom-java libxalan2-java libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libbcprov-java libreoffice-java-common

kubuntu-desktop reinstall won't help, i tried this.
Also, i have installed xfce4 to try it and xfce has same trouble with gray taskbar.(some parts are fully gray). But now plasma taskbar isn't transperent.

Comment: Okay, if i use sddm - taskbar is transperent.
https://puu.sh/xFEjj/8e4900f0b7.png

Comment: Please not that java is a "substring" of javascript (javascript-common, libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18, plasma-scriptengine-javascript). So a clean install of Kubuntu as suggested by @MichaelBay maybe the best way!

Comment: I know, it was my old broken script, that i have accidentally executed.
Well, now i can try something harder for me. Like arch linux. Nothing stops me from this.

Comment: LOL Arch Linux? Right... Good luck with that. It will be amusing to watch for sure if you try the same "stunt" in Arch. Honestly, it's much better to learn a few basic thing first. If you can't cope with the most user friendly Ubuntu (or flavors) then use Windows. Arch will be the same "disaster" x10.

Comment: Absolutely nothing stops you. All the best! BTW, Gentoo maybe even harder if that's what you're looking for.